# Cannot match any routes. for encoded url

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, urlencode, urldecode

In angular I have route path as a '/friends/message/:key/:type', for which I have a component MessageComponet
for this, I tried path '/friend/messages/NzY4OQ==/inbox'
ideally, it should navigate me to the path and MessageComponet should render

But in this scenario first I got an error as
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'friend/messages/NzY4OQ'
Not able to get params['type']

i want to access both key and type

Answer (score 0):

`=` should be encoded and when you navigate with Angular features it happens under the hood.

If you do that outside the Angular ecosystem, try this:

> the encoded route address should be `.../NzY4OQ%3D%3D/inbox` - utilize
> `encodeURIComponent('NzY4OQ==/inbox')`

See this example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-isovej)

Try to navigate with this `<button routerLink="/friend/messages/NzY4OQ==/inbox">Go To Cmp B</button>`

Comment: In my project i am not navigating to /friend/messages/NzY4OQ==/inbox
I have an independent route. where I directly hit the mentioned URL

@NgDaddy

Comment: I see. Therefore `=` must be encoded otherwise Angular cannot match that kind of wrong route address. The encoded route address should be `.../NzY4OQ%3D%3D/inbox` - utilize `encodeURIComponent('NzY4OQ==/inbox')`.